# How to sort different sized pictures to fit in the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Gwh.png

to be fixed in this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvz8G.jpg

I prefer Javascript but you can shoot different approach.

It will be a lot easier if there is already algorithm so I can have a look at it.

Thank you!

Comment: How about a library that does it http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a GitHub project that does bin-packing in javascript.  You can use this to assign positions to your html canvas drawings:

https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing/

And this code is described in this post:

http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/

If you just need to position DOM elements, here are some libraries that do rectangle fitting:

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ (using the masonry option)

http://packery.metafizzy.co/#getting-started

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it as soon as possible.